# How to use mechanize to fill search form and get results back?

Tags: python, mechanize

i am trying to use mechanize with python to search for a keyword using a a search form.
this is the form code :

```
<form id="searchform" action="http://www.example.com/" method="get">
<input id="s" type="text" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search';}" name="s" value="Search">
<input type="image" style="border:0; vertical-align: top;" src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/SimpleColor/images/search.gif">
</form>
```

i want to be able to submit and get the results back so i can extract the info from the results.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i tried many examples that i have found but i get confused. i am new to all this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [official page](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/), you create a browser object by `br = mechanize.Browser()` and follow a link with the object - `br.open("http://www.example.com/")`, and then you *select* a form by `br.select_form(name="searchform")` and you can pass an input by `br["s"] = #something` and submit it `resp = br.submit()` use the `resp` object like you wish.

Comment: how do i clean up the result and get the values out of it?